# SendGrid is not an attribute class

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, sendgrid, azure-function-app

I have installed SendGrid Nugget but I am still not able to use it in my code.
I keep getting this error:

> SendGrid is not an attribute class

[image]

Even though I think I have installed everything there is to install:

[image]

What am I missing here? Could be something silly but I am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably wanted [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid) which provides the SendGrid bindings for Azure Functions.

The basic SendGrid library knows absolutely nothing about Azure Functions.

Comment: Ooooh! I have installed `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid` and lo an behold it works!Thanks mate.
Gotta love stackoverflow!